# Get the body of a POST request in an MVC Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a WebJob that is posting a JSON object to a controller in my MVC website.

The default ModelBinder is not working correctly in this instance. Rather than troubleshoot the binder, I am perfectly happy to handle the serialization myself.

How do I get the body of the POST request from my controller Action so that I can feed it into JSON.net?

I have tried using a StreamReader on Request.InputStream, but I get an empty string.

Comment: Show us the code as it currently sits?  "Rather than troubleshoot the binder..." You'll learn a lot more that way, and save yourself some trouble. Anything in a form is accessible through the following :`FormCollection[key]` object

Comment: my approach was to create a model binder that inherits the default model binder.  If json is detected, use your json binder; if not, do the base action. Are you using C# or VB on the back end?

Comment: So I was able to figure out my binder problem - my POCO didn't expose it's public ivars as properties. But I am still interested in knowing how to get at the raw POST body out of academic curiosity.

Comment: pleas add yor POCO object code and yor view and Controller

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Angular.js $http.Post() to send a json object to my actionresult, and the Model Binding was failing. I used the below code and was able to get the json object posted and then use Newtonsoft for the DeSerialization. Interesting thing is that Newtonsoft didn't throw an error on Deserialization while the default model binding in MVC did.

```
 var req = Request.InputStream;
 var json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
```